# How to reference blob column of array from other table in sqlite

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I've been playing around sqlite for android studio while making a RPG game app until I came to these two questions:

1. Can I save an array as blob data in a table?
2. Is it possible to reference the array values in that blob column from other tables? If so, how?

Here's are the details of the problem:

There's a table called, 'monster', which is a table of enemy NPCs that has columns mon_ID, HP, MP, mon_str, mon_con, mon_dex, mon_int, drop_items.

It's the **drop_items** column that I'm trying to solve.

Some monsters have different number of drop items dropped after battle and I want to save them in the database, somehow.

Also, there is a table called, 'items', that has all the information about the items used in my game.

The drop_items column needs to be referenced from this 'items' table via item_ID.

So that's how I came up with trying to save an array list of drop items in the monster table.

If the above method is not really a good choice, can I have some other suggestions?

Comment: SQLite does not have arrays; it has tables. Make that column a separate table.

Comment: @CL. Well, I did some search and there were some ways I could save array lists from the program, such as serializing the array. Anyways, if I were to make a separate table, some of the rows will contain null column values because the table size will depend on the monster that drops the most items. This would work, but I'm trying to look for ways to do as described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a third table that links the monsters and the items. This table will just contain mon_Id and item_ID.
With this table, a monster can have several items and an item several owners.

```
mon_ID1   item_ID1
mon_ID1   item_ID2
mon_ID1   item_ID3
mon_ID2   item_ID1
mon_ID3   item_ID4
mon_ID4   item_ID5
```

Comment: I totally forgot that I can just assign same owners for the items! Thank you for the answer!